# Flutter: ffi allocator/allocate funcs

Tags: flutter, ffi

I found a library from 2020 that uses func 'allocator' and 'allocate'.

I don't know how these 2 funcs are used now.

Thanks!

Example Code:

```
Pointer<Uint8> p = allocator(count: bytes.length);
Pointer<Uint8> p1 = allocate(count: bytes2.length);
```